# Why I can't assign a variable of class to an abstract class type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the following code and it works correctly:

```
type Class<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;

abstract class AbstractClass<T = unknown> {
  constructor(protected element: T) {}

  method() {
    return "Abstract";
  }
}

class A extends AbstractClass<unknown[]> {
  constructor(element: unknown[]) {
    super(element);
  }
}

class B extends AbstractClass {
  constructor(element: unknown) {
    super(element);
  }

  method() {
    return "B";
  }
}

function factoryMethod(flag: boolean): Class<AbstractClass> {
  return flag ? A : B;
}

console.log(new (factoryMethod(true))().method());
console.log(new (factoryMethod(false))().method());
```

However, when I try to do the following I get an error:

```
const c: Class<AbstractClass> = A;
```

What I don't understand is that it works in the factoryMethod but not when I assign it directly.

The error I get is the following:

> Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'Class<AbstractClass>'. Type 'A' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: unknown[]): AbstractClass'.

Comment: "I get an error" - you forgot to mention _which_ error.

Comment: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'Class<AbstractClass<unknown>>'. Type 'A' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: unknown[]): AbstractClass<unknown>'.

Comment: Arguably neither one should work, because `A`'s constructor is allowed to assume its argument is an array, but you're not necessarily passing those, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOrqyW).  Do you agree that the real question here is why *can* you assign in `factoryMethod()` as opposed to why *can't* you assign with `c`?  If so I can investigate; if not, can you [edit] to clarify why you think so?